# Now that I actually can get this JSON data, how do I use it/loop through it?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm working on my first (EVER!) JSON project, and I'm wondering how to get specific data from a JSON object. I've imported it in, and just found out (Thank you stack overflow!) how to reference that data. I'm now able to do that, and the code below is as far as I've gotten. I have a bunch of alerts that go through the data. What I need to do now is actually loop through and evaluate the value field of the JSON shown below. I can't figure out how to select just that, and how to loop it. I've tried things like data.films.value.value , and data.films.value.value[0] , and I'm sure it's something close to that, but I can't figure out how to get the data out into a form what would let me use that specific element like a regular string. What I'm ultimately trying to do is compare each films.value element to a user entered string, and I'm not sure how to do that if I can't get the element!

```
{
    "

films": [{
        "label": "34",
        "value": "34",
        "currently_streaming": "1",
        "full_streaming_url": "http://www.url.com",
        "url": "http://www.url.com"},
    {
        "label": "A Different Color",
        "value": "A Different Color",
        "currently_streaming": "1",
        "full_streaming_url": "http://www.url.php",
        "url": "http://www.url.com"}]
}​
```

And here's the code that loads it. It returns as successful, but I can't get any of the data from the JSON object:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend : function() {
           console.log('Before Ajax Request Starts !!');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("Edddddddd");
            $.each(data.films, function(i, object) {
            $.each(object, function(property, value) {
            alert(property + "=" + value);
    });
});
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Error occurred: " + errorThrown);
        },
         beforeSend : function() {
           console.log('Ajax Request Complete  !!');
        },
        url: 'test.php'
    });  
});
```

Any and all help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
I'm now trying to loop through using the great advice I got from everyone here. This is what I have now:

```
    var test="34x25x36";
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend : function() {
           console.log('Before Ajax Request Starts !!');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("Edddddddd");
            $.each(data.films, function(i, object) {
            $.each(object, function(property, value) {
            //alert(property + "=" + value);
            for (i=0; i<data.films.length; i++){
            var theFilm = (data.films[i].value);
            if (theFilm === test){
            document.write("Your movie is hot");
            document.write(theFilm);
            }
            else {
            }
            }
    });
});
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Error occurred: " + errorThrown);
        },
         beforeSend : function() {
           console.log('Ajax Request Complete  !!');
        },
        url: 'test.php'
    });  
});
```

When I try to print out from the loop, it seems to work, but I'm having an issue. I eventually need to compare this data to some user input, which I've defined at the top for testing purposes as var test. I want it to compare each variable to test, but for some reason, it seems to be SETTING each variable to test. Is there something wrong with my loop?

Comment: didn't you ask this question already?

Comment: Yes! Someone taught me how to pull the data, but I couldn't figure out how to reference it!

Answer (score 0):

Try

`films[0].label` will give you 34

To iterate you need to use

```
$.each(data.films, function(i, object) { 
// And Not 
$.each(json.films, function(i, object) {
```

Try This

**UPDATED CODE:**

Because eacy arrach item is inturn an Object you need to write up one more loop to access what is inside them..

```
$.each(data.films, function() {
    $.each(this, function(j, val) {
        console.log('Key - ' + j + ' :: Value - ' + val);
    });
});​
```

This Should work in your case

```
function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert("Edddddddd");
    $.each(data.films, function(i, object) {
        $.each(object, function(property, value) {
            alert(property + "=" + value);
        });
    });
}​
```

// Using For Loop

```
var keys = ["label", "value", "currently_streaming", "full_streaming_url", "url"]
for (i = 0; i < data.films.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        alert( 'Key - ' + keys[j] + ' :: Value - ' + data.films[i][keys[j]] )  ;
    }
}​
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yHQtp/1/)

Comment: Ugh, that didn't work for me when I wrote alert(films[0].label); unless I'm doing something wrong (which I probably am!)

Comment: This is what I have now: success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("Edddddddd");
            $.each(data.films, function(i, object) {
            $.each(object, function(property, value) {
            //alert(property + "=" + value);
   alert(films[0].label);
    }); Should that work?

Comment: That works! Thank you! To interate, do I write $.each(data.films[i].label)?

Comment: Check the updated code... Because each array item is again a Object you need to iterate it over again.. Try this

Comment: Hmmm, this isn't working for me:  $.each(object, function(property, value) {
            //alert(property + "=" + value);
   alert ($.each(data.films[0].value));
    });

Comment: Try this  $.each(data.films, function() {
    $.each(this, function(j, val) {
        console.log('Key - ' + j + ' :: Value - ' + val);
    });
});​

Comment: Now I've got this, but it doesn't seem to work: success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("Edddddddd");
            $.each(data.films, function(i, object) { 
   //$.each(data.films, function(i, object) {
           $.each(object, function(property, value) {
            //alert(property + "=" + value);
   
   alert (films[0].label);
    });
 });

Comment: Sorry, for some reason didn't reload and see this til now. Thank you!

Comment: Try this .. This should work for you function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert("Edddddddd");
    $.each(data.films, function(i, object) {
        $.each(object, function(property, value) {
            alert(property + "=" + value);
        });
    });
}​

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps. It seems like the loop is pulling everything. Is there a way to pull just the value of value?

Comment: What if I write a for loop? for (i=0, i=data.films.length; i++){
   alert(data.films[i].value);
   }

Comment: A for loop also will work.. check this http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Uqwnb/ .. Also posted the code using for loop .. Check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
  for (var item in data.films) {
    alert(item.label);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that keeps coming back undefined

Comment: You might have newlines in your json name (if your example matches your code). In your json, try `"films":` instead of `"/n/nfilms:"`

Comment: I mean how your quote starts on one line, then there are two empty lines, and then `films:"`, \n is the representation of a new line in programming, you'll see it everywhere now i'm sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Your tried to loop on **json.films** instead of **data.films** ...

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "films": [{  // <-- to access this data.films
        "label": "34",  // to access this data.films[0].label - this is the first object in the array
        "value": "34",  // to access this data.films[0].value
        "currently_streaming": "1", //  // to access this data.films[0].currently_streaming
        "full_streaming_url": "http://www.url.com", // and so on
        "url": "http://www.url.com"} // and so on
    {
        "label": "A Different Color", // to access this data.films[1].label - this is the second object in the array
        // arrays are zero indexed
        "value": "A Different Color", // to access this data.films[1].value
        "currently_streaming": "1",
        "full_streaming_url": "http://www.url.php",
        "url": "http://www.url.com"}]
}​
```

So when you loop - you want to loop where the array is..

```
$.each(data.films, function(k,v){
    console.log(v.value); // <-- this will give you the value for both
    // now that you're here you can get value for each property by 
    // v.label
    // v.value
    // v.currently_streaming
    // v.full_streaming_url
    // v.url
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KPkWe/

Comment: Thank you! I just tried a for loop to loop through them, but it doesn't seem to be working. for (i=0; i=data.films.length; i++){
   alert(data.films[i].value);
   }

Comment: Change `i=data.films.length` to `i<data.films.length`, or use `$.each` as in sushanth reddy's answer.

Comment: This works, thank you! I couldn't figure out the $.each - I'm pretty new to jQuery, too.

Comment: Is what I have here ok?     success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("Edddddddd");
            $.each(data.films, function(i, object) {
            $.each(object, function(property, value) {
            //alert(property + "=" + value);
   for (i=0; i<data.films.length; i++){
   var theFilm = (data.films[i].value);
   document.write(theFilm+"<br>");
   }

Comment: It's hard to answer that, since there's no formatting in comments. Edit it into your question.

Comment: @usk = look at this example.. you should be able to see how I'm doing this http://jsfiddle.net/xU7MS/

Comment: I just updated it with my current code. I'm not sure if the loop is ok. Thank you @wirey ! Let me try your code, because mine seems to be having issues.

Comment: I can't actually get that to run in my current setup. Am I inserting it wrong? Let me try updating the fiddler with what I'm doing locally.

Comment: If you can make a fiddle of your issue it would help a lot

Comment: @USK sorry was busy doing some work.. But are you sure your response is coming back correctly?  Best way to check is to hit the ajax url - with the required parameters if there are any - directly and see what the response is